# EXT JS 5 : why can I not get the model object of my reference type

Tags: javascript, extjs, model, getter, extjs5

I have the following model :

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Container', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.model',


    requires : ['MyApp.model.Item','MyApp.model.User'],


    items : [
        {
            name : 'user',
            mapping : 'user',
            reference : 'MyApp.model.User',
            unique : true
        },
        {
            name : 'item',
            mapping : 'item',
            reference : 'MyApp.model.Item'
        }
    ],


    //******************************
    //*      GETTERS / SETTERS     *
    //******************************
    getUser : function() {
        var me = this;
        return me.get('user');
    },


    getItem: function() {
        var me = this;
        return me.get('item');
    }
});
```

And when I get user or item, I don't get an User model or Item model, but an Object.
How can I get an Item model or an User model instead of an Object.

Edit 1 :

I found a solution but I don't know if it's a good solution :

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Container', {
    [...]    

    //******************************
    //*      GETTERS / SETTERS     *
    //******************************
    getUser : function() {
        var me = this;
        return new MyApp.model.User(me.get('user'));
    },


    getItem: function() {
        var me = this;
        return new MyApp.model.Item(me.get('item'));
    }
});
```

Edit 2 :

With my first example, when I load my store, I get this when I get User for example :

```
store
    => getAt(0)
        => data
            => item [...]
            => utilisateur
                => id : '1'
                => name : 'john doe'
                => profil : 'admin'
```

And i want :

```
store
    => getAt(0)
        => data
            => item [...]
            => utilisateur
                => $className : "MyApp.model.User"
                => id : '1'
                => name : 'john doe'
                => profil : 'admin'
                => (others properties of model object)
                => (getters and setters functions)
```

Edit 3 :

Sorry ... my problem is that I use items for my field declaration and not fields................

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Container', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.model',


    requires : ['MyApp.model.Item','MyApp.model.User'],


    fields : [
        {
            name : 'user',
            mapping : 'user',
            reference : 'MyApp.model.User',
            unique : true
        },
        {
            name : 'item',
            mapping : 'item',
            reference : 'MyApp.model.Item'
        }
    ],


    //******************************
    //*      GETTERS / SETTERS     *
    //******************************
    getUser : function() {
        var me = this;
        var user = me.user;
        if(user) {
            return user;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    },

    getItem: function() {
        var me = this;
        var item = me.item;
        if(item) {
            return item;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
});
```

Regards.

Comment: `model.get` "Returns the value of the given field". See: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-get

Comment: Are you sure you're not confusing models with stores?

Comment: @mustafa.0x I don't understand your first comment because I want values of my field user or item ​but as a model object not as a simple javascript object.

Comment: But if you have a record from a store then that is already a model instance. So you can do: record.get('user'), as record is a model object. So maybe that is what Mustafa is trying to point out to you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For the answer, be carreful of the name of your config and look the third Edit.

Answer (score 0):

The reference field already looks in the folder where your models are stored so you just need fix the reference config.

```
items : [
    {
        name : 'user',
        mapping : 'user',
        reference : 'User', <---
        unique : true
    },
    {
        name : 'item',
        mapping : 'item',
        reference : 'Item' <--
    }
]
```

You also do not need to define the functions to get the models as Ext will automatically add getUser() and getItem().